# How to block code to wait for a connection

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ive been boxing around with a new api for some sensorTag. I need to wait for the connection to settle or my code piece will fail the first time tis ran. I have the following code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.sensorGyro = [MSBSensorUV createObjectGyro];
if(self.sensorGyro){
    while (!self.sensorGyro.client.isDeviceConnected) {
        NSLog(@"Awaiting connection");
    }//Check that connection has been made

    NSLog(@"connection UP");

        [self.sensorGyro.client.sensorManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:nil errorRef:nil withHandler:^(MSBSensorGyroData *GyroData, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Starting updates");
            self.currentGyroLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", GyroData.GyroIndexLevel];
        }];
```

Initially I didn't have the while loop. I used a 2-3sec dispatch_after call. But I felt it was not good waiting a fixed time, better would be to proceed when connected. But When I use the while loop my app just stalls and stops working. no crash, just stop. Can anybody tell me why this is happening. since I have verified the connection only takes like 2 sec, I don't see a problem doing the while loop? Also, is there a better way to "wait" for stuff to finish/get dry.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MSBSensorUV` class is starting some asynchronous connection process.

1. If you're going to loop waiting for the status to change, you could dispatch that to a background thread (as Luke cryptically suggested). That prevents the app from blocking the main thread.

   The problem is that you still have a thread tied up in an wasteful exercise constantly polling to see if `isDeviceConnected` is true yet. It's the programmatic equivalent of a child in the back seat of a car constantly asking "are we there yet?"
2. Better, you could adopt an event driven pattern, such as using KVO as suggested by Matteo. This way rather than this code constantly polling, you will be notified when the `isDeviceConnected` property changes.

   This is far more efficient and is a great approach if you're stuck with a class that doesn't provide a completion block, but does change some property asynchronously.
3. Best, because `MSBSensorUV` is your own class, you could refactor it to provide a connection complete handler block. That way, you avoid the complications introduced by the above approaches.

---

Offline, you shared a bit of the `MSBSensorUV` implementation:

```
+ (MSBSensorUV *)createObjectUV{
    static MSBSensorUV *UVObject;
    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        UVObject = [[MSBSensorUV alloc]init];
    });
    return UVObject;
}

- (MSBSensorUV *)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [MSBClientManager sharedManager].delegate = self;
        NSArray *clients = [[MSBClientManager sharedManager] attachedClients];
        self.client = [clients firstObject];
        if(self.client == nil){
            //no bands attached
            return nil;
        }
        [[MSBClientManager sharedManager] connectClient:self.client];
    }
    return self;
}
```

First, `createObjectUV` is creating a singleton, so you should rename it to something like `sharedSensor` (using prefix of `shared` makes it clear that you're dealing with a singleton):

```
+ (instancetype)sharedSensor {
    static MSBSensorUV *uvObject;
    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        uvObject = [[MSBSensorUV alloc] init];
    });
    return uvObject;
}
```

Second, `init` should not start the connection.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [MSBClientManager sharedManager].delegate = self;
        NSArray *clients = [[MSBClientManager sharedManager] attachedClients];
        self.client = [clients firstObject];
        if(self.client == nil){
            //no bands attached
            return nil;
        }
        // [[MSBClientManager sharedManager] connectClient:self.client];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Frankly, in the context of a singleton, the notion of returning `nil` if there are no bands attached probably doesn't make sense (because once you've set it to `nil`, you can never access this singleton again until you terminate the app). So you probably want to pull that logic out of `init`, too, but I'll let you tackle that on your own.

Third, you would declare a property for the connection completion handler:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^connectionCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSError *);
```

Fourth, you would create a `connectionWithCompletionHandler` method, e.g.:

```
- (void)connectWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))block
{
    self.connectionCompletionHandler = block;
    
    [[MSBClientManager sharedManager] connectClient:self.client];
}
```

Your connection delegate methods would then call this completion handler, e.g. `clientDidConnect` would call:

```
if (self.connectionCompletionHandler) {
    self.connectionCompletionHandler(TRUE, nil);
    self.connectionCompletionHandler = nil;
}
```

And `didFailToConnectWithError` would report failure:

```
if (self.connectionCompletionHandler) {
    self.connectionCompletionHandler(FALSE, error);
    self.connectionCompletionHandler = nil;
}
```

Finally, going back to your original code sample, it would look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.sensorGyro = [MSBSensorUV sharedSensor];
    [self.sensorGyro connectWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"connection UP");
            [self.sensorGyro.client.sensorManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:nil errorRef:nil withHandler:^(MSBSensorGyroData *GyroData, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Starting updates");
                self.currentGyroLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", GyroData.GyroIndexLevel];
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **KVO** and so observe the variable:

`self.sensorGyro.client.isDeviceConnected`

When the **variable changes**, the **observer** receives a notification.

So you should initially display a spinner (loading), and setting:

`self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

then, when you will receive the notification, you should remove the spinner and set the user interaction to enabled (YES).

Add an observer is easy:

```
[self.sensorGyro.client addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isDeviceConnected" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

You must add this method, which will be called when the variable changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isDeviceConnected"]) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Finally remember to remove the observer in the method `-dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.self.sensorGyro.client removeObserver:self ....];
}
```

**Important:
The notification is auto-sent just if the property `isDeviceConnected` is set using the accessor method, so: `self.isDeviceConnected`.**

For further information I suggest you to read the [Apple documentation about KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA).

Comment: is -dealloc called in response to observeValueForkeyPath:.....? Or how is the call being invoked. Also whats "meaning" behind OptionOld vs ....OptionNew? Thanks for your answer, I still don't understand why the while loop isn't working.

Comment: @Rob I was just wondering how -dealloc was being invoked since its not like say ViewDidDisappear that is automatically invoked at some action done. Also about that loop, I fully understand that this isn't at all optimal in a language that incorporates observers etc. I just don't understand why it wouldn't work, 15 years ago I used it:)

Comment: @Rob thats a few good points you are making there indeed about the loop. Just for clarification, when you say dealloc is called automatically when object is released do you mean the "self" object? Why is it not part of the standard template like viewdidunload and viewdiddisappear then?

Comment: @Rob another thing if u don't mind. The answer below recommending dispatch_async. Does that make sense?; I did make a comment on it below. The dispatch use would be less consuming on most parts, but I don't see it working. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DevilInDisguise - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75014/discussion-between-rob-and-devilindisguise).

Comment: If you ask me about `dealloc`, this means you should study a bit more about the memory management before thinking to continue to write code. `dealloc` is automatically called when an object is deallocated. Now your question could be "when an object is deallocated?"..study. Option old and new are just values that will be in the dictionary when the method will be called. The method will be called automatically when the variable change. You cannot use the while approach because you are gonna block the thread and anyway it is not a good practice do that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `dispatch_async` command.

Essentially you will be adding a level of multithreading capability to your code. I may be wrong, but I would rewrite your code similar to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.sensorGyro = [MSBSensorUV createObjectGyro];
if(self.sensorGyro){
    while (!self.sensorGyro.client.isDeviceConnected) {
        NSLog(@"Awaiting connection");
    }//Check that connection has been made

    NSLog(@"connection UP");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self.sensorGyro.client.sensorManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:nil errorRef:nil withHandler:^(MSBSensorGyroData *GyroData, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Starting updates");
         self.currentGyroLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", GyroData.GyroIndexLevel];
    });
}];
```

Comment: How does that "hold" the call? Im not sure about it, but it seems to me async might as well fail initially, unless the delay for it to be called on main thread is "slow enough." Also, can I do any use of isDeviceConnected member wit dispatch_async?

Comment: I just tried putting the -startGyroUpdatesToQueue:: in a dispatch_async block. Still persists with the same problem

Comment: Your app shouldn't need to 'hold'. Just wait for the async call to come back and then call your setup code.

Comment: This is a really weak answer. May I suggest adding a bit more detail to make it useful.

Comment: @Msencenb Hmm, I still think it needs to "hold"/wait, because if not, the connection won't be established yet. Using dispatch_async will queue the call, but async willr return immediately, so I don't understand how this would work. Could you pls specify where to put the dispatch_async, because what i tried didn't work.. as stated above